# Ajax call pulling in random html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to solve. First thing is first. I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache and php5. I am using the netbeans IDE which i originally assumed to be the issue but then i ran it directly from the web root /var/www/html. php is working i already tested it. i can run html pages and php pages from the root. I have developed a few applications already using this computer. Some which use very advanced ajax to calls to google apis. I have no idea why all of a sudden I can't make the simplest ajax call. Anyways the problem is that when I make my ajax call to a php file nothing happens. if i inspect the page in browser, it shows that it pulled in a bunch of random iframes. I have never used an iframe before. I am really hoping that I just need a different set of eyes on this and that it isn't something else.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index HTML</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "getHTML.php",
                data: { "test": "testing"},
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                statusCode: {
                    0: function () {
                        alert("Thank You");
                    },
                    200: function (html) {
                        $("#page").append(html);
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">The Div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

getHTML.php

```
    <?php
       echo "Hello World";
    ?>
```

After running this in mozilla firefox, no iframes are being pulled in. I can only assume it is some bug with chrome. So now to answer the question: why aren't I getting any response from the ajax call?

So I am now getting a response from my ajax calls. Way worse though. I changes my $.ajax to a $.post() and then to a $.get() and now it is return a duplicate of index.html over and over and over in an infinite loop. From what i understand the default url that $.get/post take is the current url. But I added getHTML.php as the url argument. so I am at a loss. I can't get any work done if I can't solve this issue. Can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("getHTML.php", function(data)
        $("body").append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're not using iframes then there's a strong possibility some exploit is.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use JSON for these requests:

```
$return_data = array();
if (condition){
   $return_data['status'] = 'success';
} else {
    $return_data['status'] = 'info';
}

echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
```

Remember to specify return data type:

```
function send() {
var data = $('#signup_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "signup_process.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data.status);
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                // everything went alright, submit
                $('#signup_form').submit();
            } else if (data.status == 'info')
            {
                console.log(data.status);
                $("label#email_error").show(); 
                return false; 
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution to this issue has nothing to do with any programming. For the iframes, this way a strange google chrome issue, luckily it doesn't affect the visuals as nothing displays. As far as the ajax problem, I was doing it right (tested on a different computer) but the Apache2 server was not responding to ajax requests. It is gonna take some time searching through log files to find a proper solution.